# How to get last 7 days when date format is yyyymdd

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is my database structure for date:
[image]

I want to get 3 results that are `2017/9/22`  `2017/9/24`  `2017/9/25` if today is `2017/9/29`.

On my DatabaseHandler class I have tried the following code :

```
public List<Contact> latestDays() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        // My database time format is: yyyymdd
        Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String today = String.valueOf(mYear).concat(String.valueOf(mMonth).concat(String.valueOf(mDay)));
        System.out.println(today+"today");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE date > (SELECT DATETIME('" + today + "'," + "'-7" + " day'))";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
//looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setBeforeMorning(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setAfterMorning(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setBeforeNoon(cursor.getString(4));
                contact.setAfterNoon(cursor.getString(5));
                contact.setBeforeNight(cursor.getString(6));
                contact.setAfterNight(cursor.getString(7));
                System.out.println("The result is :" + cursor.getString(1));
                //Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contactList;
    }
```

I call it on my MainActivity like this:

```
private DatabaseHandler db;
contactList = db.latestDays();
System.out.println(contactList.size());
```

I print the result it like this:
[image]

I get all of my records but it's not what I want.

The reason probably is my date format, so I add my sorting all date by yyyymmdd to the raqQuery:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS +" WHERE date > (SELECT DATETIME('" + today + "'," + "'-7" + " day'))" +
                " ORDER BY\n" +
                " SUBSTR(Date, 1, 4) DESC,\n" +
                " CASE WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') = 2\n" +
                " THEN '0' || SUBSTR(Date, 6, 1)\n" +
                " ELSE SUBSTR(Date, 6, 2) END DESC,\n" +
                " CASE WHEN LENGTH(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)) = 1\n" +
                " THEN '0' || SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)\n" +
                " ELSE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1) END DESC; ",null);
```

I still get the same result...

So I tried to find another solution and tried like this, I change SQL search syntax:

```
        Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String today = String.valueOf(mYear).concat(String.valueOf(mMonth).concat(String.valueOf(mDay)));
        System.out.println(today+"today");
        Calendar theEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar theStart = (Calendar) theEnd.clone();

        theStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd");
        String start = dateFormat.format(theStart.getTime());
        String end = dateFormat.format(theEnd.getTime());

        // Now you have date boundaries in TEXT format

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE date BETWEEN "+start+" AND "+end +
                        " ORDER BY\n" +
                        " SUBSTR(Date, 1, 4) DESC,\n" +
                        " CASE WHEN INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') = 2\n" +
                        " THEN '0' || SUBSTR(Date, 6, 1)\n" +
                        " ELSE SUBSTR(Date, 6, 2) END DESC,\n" +
                        " CASE WHEN LENGTH(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)) = 1\n" +
                        " THEN '0' || SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1)\n" +
                        " ELSE SUBSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), INSTR(SUBSTR(Date, 6), '/') + 1) END DESC; ", null);
```

Its more worse , i don't get any data.
[image]

How exactly do I get my latest 7 days if my database time format is yyyymdd ?

Comment: Could You share project/mocked project on github?

Comment: for you sanity store dates in some sortable format ... fx as `LONG` (as milis) or in format `yyyy/mm/dd` (both days and moths with leading zeros) ... then obviously **even if sorted as string** `2017/10/1` will be greater than `2017/9/31`   (which is not true with your format) as 9 > 1 ... it is all because **there is no DATETIME type in sqlite** (at 2017-09)

Comment: @deadfish do you mean upload this file on github right ?

Comment: that's right, on github

Comment: @deadfish I have upload the file `DatabaseHandler.java` on my github https://github.com/motogod/latestDays  , the function i try is `latestDays()` . Please take a look , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
final LocalDate currentDate= LocalDate.now();
final LocalDate date7Days = date.minusDays(7);
//Format and display date
final String formattedDate = date7Days.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

change according your date time format

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i can't find LocalDate and i have try yyyymmdd in my last try. Still include my first and second try.